# I need to create a new column or alter the original from array<string> to map<string,int> where int values are in new table for respective string

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have two tables.
 1.table1:(string,array(string))

```
abc ["s","m"]
def ["m","a","l"]
xyz ["s","a"]
```

2.table2:(string,int)

```
m 12
s 26
l 57
a 45
```

Now i want a table like below:(string,map(string,int))

```
abc ["s":26,"m":12]
def ["m":12,"a":45,"l":57]
xyz ["s":26,"a":45]
```

1. I need **HIVE** query for doing this.
2. How to interate for a purticular row sum like

```
abc 38
```

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag, since it has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: representation is not `map(string,int))` it's `array<string: string>`

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick

```
select t1.cat, collect_list(concat_ws(":", t1.subs, cast(t2.cnt as string))) from 
(select cat, subs from temp.table1
lateral view explode(sub) s as subs) t1
join 
    temp.table2 t2
on
    t1.subs = t2.sub
group by t1.cat
```

And if you want to do a sum based on the above table.

```
select cat, sum(split(sub, ":")[1]) from temp.test3
lateral view explode(`_c1`) c as sub
group by cat
```